# The first slide in GlideJS is flashing

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, glidejs

When changing slides in the slider with some periodicity, the first slide flashes when changing from the first to the last slide.

The bug only appears in Chrome. I noticed that if you minimize the browser window and then maximize, then the bug appears more often ( but this is not certain :) ).

The solution from https://github.com/glidejs/glide/issues/300 doesn't help!

I put together a small demo: https://codepen.io/depressingutopian/pen/jOwvpGQ?editors=1111

[image: demo]

```js
const initCarousel = () => {
    const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.glide__slide');
    if (slides.length) {
        const sliderConfiguration = {
            gap: 0,
            type: 'carousel',
            autoplay: '1000',
            animationDuration: '500',
            hoverpause: false,
            keyboard: true,
            animationTimingFunc: 'cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.840, 0.440, 1.000)',
            swipeThreshold: 0,
            dragThreshold: false
        };
        const slider = new Glide('.map-banner', sliderConfiguration);
        slider.mount();
    }
}

initCarousel();
```

```css
.section-default {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'FiraSans';
  font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  min-width: 320px;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling:  touch;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

.layout {
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-flex;
    display: -ms-flex;
    display: -o-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -moz-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -o-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.layout__content {
   -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.mb-p, .mb-sm {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.color-common {
    color: #424242;
}
body, html {
    font-family: 'FiraSans';
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}

.map-banner {
    margin: 1.5rem auto 0;
    width: 79rem;
    cursor: default;
}

.glide--swipeable {
    cursor: grab;
    cursor: -moz-grab;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
}
.glide {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.map-banner .glide__slide_narrow {
        padding: 0 1.5rem;
    }

 .map-banner .glide__arrow {
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        border-radius: 0;
        box-shadow: none;
    }

 .map-banner .glide__arrow_prev {
        left: -5px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(90deg);
  }

  .map-banner .glide__arrow_next {
        right: -5px;
        transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(270deg);
   }

   .map-banner .glide__arrow-img {
        width: 2rem;
        height: 2rem;
   }

.map-banner .map-banner__transfer {
    img {
        height: 12rem;
    }
}

.slider {
    img {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.map-banner__main {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 24rem;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.glide__track {
  
  margin-left: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.map-banner__main_0 {
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/gleemJV.png');
}

.map-banner__main_1 {
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/oF41CCc.png');
}

.map-banner__main_2 {
    background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/oEVQL4F.png');
}

// Flickering bug fix (Attempt)
.glide__slide--active {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@glidejs/glide@3.3.0/dist/css/glide.core.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@glidejs/glide" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="section-default platform_unknown">
  <div class="layout layout_full_height color-common">
    <div class="layout__content">
      <section class="mb-sm mb-mob-none">
         <div class="glide map-banner">
            <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
               <ul class="glide__slides">
                  <li class="glide__slide slider">
                    <img class ="map-banner__main" src="https://i.imgur.com/gleemJV.png"/>
                  </li>
                  <li class="glide__slide slider">
                     <img class ="map-banner__main" src="https://i.imgur.com/oF41CCc.png"/>
                  </li>
                  <li class="glide__slide slider">
                     <img class ="map-banner__main" src="https://i.imgur.com/oEVQL4F.png"/>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would be grateful to everyone who can help fix this bug.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to add z-index:1 in the active slide.

```
.glide__slide--active{z-index: 1;}
```